Альтернатива textarea
Существуют готовый вариант <div contenteditable>, где я мог бы сам настроить, какие символы или строки будут выделяться нужным цветом?
Вчера попробовал это сделать, но вышло 50/50 и поэтому удалил. Мне это нужно не для работы с кодами, а для своей разметки в текстах.
Например, если строка начинается с //, то она вся зеленая. Или теги свой разметки [BR], [P] и т.д. выделить синим цветом.
P.S. Также не хватает CSS кастомизации для <textarea>.

угу впрочем, есть ли возможность добавить именно свой скин(отличный от тех которые в той либе уже есть) не уверен.

@puffleeck Так это целая либа с компонентами, нельзя ли сделать что-нибудь попроще, своими руками?

@RomanC, можно конечно. например тут вариант от UModeL хорош. в принципе, там же ниже есть и вариант с наброском на PureCSS... но до вменяемого вида там далеко, да и интерактив всё равно пришлось бы делать на JS.

@puffleeck Так там цвет кидается с отступами на текст и не привязан к самому тексту.
